# Error al crear fichero para mandar por whatsapp

Tags: java, android

Quiero enviar por whatsapp un fichero pero tengo dos problemas:

1.- Cuando llega al "checkExternalStoragePermissionTurno()" siempre se sale por " ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityWhatsapp.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);" aunque nunca me pide si quiero aceptar los permisos y por supuesto nunca ejecuta el procedimiento  "turnocrearpdf()"

2.- Si fuerzo para que llege al procedimiento "turnocrearpdf()" se sale por el "catch (FileNotFoundException e)" es decir fila no encontrada y es en esta linea donde se sale
" PdfWriter pdfwrite = PdfWriter.getInstance( document, new FileOutputStream( nombre_completo.toString() ) );"

En otra App tengo exactamente lo mismo y si funciona includo el AndroidManifest.xml

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        checkExternalStoragePermissionTurno();
                    } else {
                        turnocrearpdf();
                    }


  private void checkExternalStoragePermissionTurno() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            ActivityWhatsapp.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityWhatsapp.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 225);
    } else {
        turnocrearpdf();
    }
}

 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private void turnocrearpdf() {
    try {
        Document document = new Document( PageSize.LETTER );
        String ARCHIVO = "TotalTurnos"+  gmnombreoposicion + ".pdf";

        File destinoPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), CARPETA);
        if (!destinoPath.exists()) { destinoPath.mkdir(); }

        File nombre_completo = new File( destinoPath + File.separator + ARCHIVO);
        if (!nombre_completo.exists()) { nombre_completo.delete(); }
        PdfWriter pdfwrite = PdfWriter.getInstance( document, new FileOutputStream( nombre_completo.toString() ) );


        // Creamos el documento para escribirlo
        document.open();
        document.addTitle( "Porcentaje Oposición Total y Turnos" );

        XMLWorkerHelper xmlWorkerHelper = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

        htmlToPdf = "<html>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "<table width=\"800\" border=\"10\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"2\">\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "   <td align=\"center\" colspan=\"4\"><h1><font color=\"#d63031\">Porcentaje Oposición Total y Turnos</font></h1></td>\n" +
                "</tr>\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "   <td align=\"center\" colspan=\"4\"><font color=\"#6D4C41\"><h3>Total: " + gmstringtotal + " ====== Presentados: "+ gmstringpresentado +
                " ====== %: " + gmstringporciento + "</h3></font></td>\n"+
                "</tr>\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"350\"><strong><u>Turnos</u></strong></td>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"100\" align=\"center\"><strong><u>Total</u></strong></td>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"100\" align=\"center\"><strong><u>Presentado</u></strong></td>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"100\" align=\"center\"><strong><u>Porciento</u></strong></td>\n" +
                "</tr>\n";
        htmlToPdf = htmlToPdf + " <tr>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"400\">" + "\n" + "Libre" + "</td>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">" + gmstringlibretotal + "</td>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">" + gmstringlibrepresentados + "</td>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"100\" align=\"center\">" + gmstringlibreporciento + "</td>\n" +
                " </tr>  ";
        htmlToPdf = htmlToPdf + " <tr>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"400\">" + "\n" + "Interna" + "</td>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">" + gmstringinternatotal + "</td>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">" + gmstringinternapresentados + "</td>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"100\" align=\"center\">" + gmstringinternaporciento + "</td>\n" +
                " </tr>  ";
        htmlToPdf = htmlToPdf + " <tr>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"400\">" + "\n" + "Discapacidad" + "</td>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">" + gmstringdiscapacidadtotal + "</td>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"100\" align=\"right\">" + gmstringdiscapacidadpresentados + "</td>\n" +
                "   <td width=\"100\" align=\"center\">" + gmstringdiscapacidadporciento + "</td>\n" +
                " </tr>  ";
        htmlToPdf = htmlToPdf + "</table>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>\n";

        try {
            xmlWorkerHelper.parseXHtml( pdfwrite, document, new StringReader(htmlToPdf) );
            document.close();
            try {
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(ActivityWhatsapp.this, ActivityWhatsapp.this.getPackageName() + ".provider", nombre_completo);
                gmtelefono = String.valueOf(telefonoEditext.getText());
                String numTelefono = "34" + gmtelefono;
                final Intent compartir = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                        //.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, destinatarios)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Envio de archivos PDF")
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Se adjunta archivo")
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
                        .putExtra("jid", numTelefono + "@s.whatsapp.net")
                        .setPackage("com.whatsapp")
                        .setType("application/pdf");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(compartir, "Compartir PDF"));

            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityWhatsapp.this, "Whatsapp no esta instalado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogCopiaError = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityWhatsapp.this);
            alertDialogCopiaError.setMessage("No se pudo realizar el PDF. Intentelo más tarde.")
                    .setTitle("ERROR Creando PDF")
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.pdf48)
                    .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                    });
            alertDialogCopiaError.show();
        }

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogCopiaError = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityWhatsapp.this);
        alertDialogCopiaError.setMessage("No se pudo realizar el PDF. Intentelo más tarde.")
                .setTitle("ERROR Creando PDF")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.pdf48)
                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                });
        alertDialogCopiaError.show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogCopiaError = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityWhatsapp.this);
        alertDialogCopiaError.setMessage("aaaaaaaaNo se pudo realizar el PDF. Intentelo más tarde.")
                .setTitle("ERROR Creando PDF")
                .setIcon(R.drawable.pdf48)
                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
                });
        alertDialogCopiaError.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes declarado el permiso en tu archivo `Manifest`?

Comment: Si. Estos som   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />